# Android SQLite - Update not working however db.update does return 1

Tags: android, sqlite

Ok this is another puzzle - So basically trying to update a record - it fails

however db.update method does return 1 indicating success.

Table SQL is:

```
public String getSQL() {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions ( " +
            "transactionid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "accountid INTEGER, "+
            "amount REAL, " +
            "transactiontype INTEGER, " +
            "checknumber TEXT, " +
            "checkdate TEXT, " +
            "cleared INTEGER," +
            "notes TEXT," +
            "categoryid INTEGER)";
    }
```

Values for the update are provided using following way. I have made sure that record does exist.

```
dbh.updateRecord(values, "transactions", "transactionid", Integer.toString(selTrans.getTransactionID()) );
```

Where updateRecord method is defined as:

```
public void updateRecord(ContentValues values, String tableName, String pkName, String pkValue) {
        SQLiteDatabase db=null; 

        try {
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            int ret = db.update(tableName, values,pkName + " =?", new String[] {pkValue} );
            Log.v("jv", "Update Record is : " + ret);

        } catch(Exception e) { Log.v("jv", "Updating Record: " + e.toString());  }
    }
```

Upon printing **Update Record is: 1** => indicating success of update operation.

But when transaction value is retrieved => new value is not reflected indicating no update.

I have tried following things:

-1 Using SQL format
-2 Using String.valueOf for PKValue
-3 Using beingTransaction/transactioNSuccessful/endTransaction

None seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?